# How to add Multiple recipients and cc using php

Tags: php, sendgrid

to add multiable email recipents in php:

```
$email->addTo("email1@hotmail.com", "name1");

$email->addTo("email2@hotmail.com", "name2");
```

to add multiable cc email recipients in php:

```
$email->addCc("email3@hotmail.com", "name3");

$email->addCc("email4@hotmail.com", "name4");
```

I tried this code and got error,
how to properly add cc and multiple users.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: is this the answer to your question https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations#sending-a-single-email-to-a-single-recipient-with-a-cc

Answer (score 0):

```
$ccEmails = [
    "test+5@example.com" => "Example User5",
    "test+6@example.com" => "Example User6"
];
$email->addCcs($ccEmails);
```

or try it like this